# Comma use: Finally, only 10% of patients, being not admitted to hospital care, received rehabilitation

Tags: british-english, commas

> Finally, only 10% of patients, being not admitted to hospital care, received rehabilitation.

> Finally, only 10% of patients, not admitted to hospital care,
> received rehabilitation.

How should I use commas within the aforementioned sentence?

Comment: The second sentence makes sense with only the first comma.  I don't understand what the first one is trying to say.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite for more clarity.

Comment: Do you mean that of the patients who didn't get hospital care, 10% of them got rehab? Then @Ryan has it: other than "Finally," you must have no commas.